# Solr index doesn't load automatically on startup

Tags: solr, indexing, dataimporthandler

1. Hi, I'm using solr 4.6.1 and when I start up the system solr doesn't automatically index the database, nor does it access the data previously indexed. How can i do it?
2. Also when i press execute on the dataimport handler tab after selecting the table and trying full-import, it shows "indexing" but doesn't really come out of it till i press refresh status. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

1. Solr never use auto index .. you have to tell solr to index data using UI or command line.
2. Its not error you either tick auto refresh button or refresh after indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but once its on the production server it can't be done manually right? There must be an alternative.

Comment: Yea, You can write a cron job for that ... like ..              simple add this line to your crontab with crontab -e command:

0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://<solr_host>:8983/solr/<core_name>/dataimport?command=full-import 
This will full import every 30 minutes. Replace <solr_host> and <core_name> with your configuration